# WPF TextBlock not showing customizations

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that loads pictures from an erp document handling source and allows them to be moved and resized by touch or mouse. There is a class called Picture:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DocumentHandlingTouch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Picture.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Picture : UserControl
    {
      
        public Picture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
          
        }

        public string ImagePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImagePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value); }
        }

        public string ImageName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageName", typeof(string), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImagePath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImagePath", typeof(string), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

        public string OriginalImagePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(OriginalImagePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OriginalImagePathProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalImagePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("OriginalImagePath", typeof(string), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

        public double Angle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));

        


        public double ScaleX
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleXProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleXProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ScaleX.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleXProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleX", typeof(double), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0));

        public double ScaleY
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleYProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleYProperty, value); }
        }
    
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ScaleY.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleYProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleY", typeof(double), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0));

        public double X
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(XProperty); }
            set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for X.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(double), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));


        public double Y
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(YProperty); }
            set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Y.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double), typeof(Picture), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
    }
}
```

Here is the class that loads the pictures. It uses a textbox under the picture to display the filename:

```
    private void LoadPictures()
    {

        _canvas.Children.Clear();
        double x = -10;
        double y = 0;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry filePath in files)
        {

            try
            {

                Picture p = new Picture();
                ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
                t.Content = filePath.Value;
                p.ToolTip = t;
///////////////////Heres where the textblock is set////////////////
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
                tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBlack;
                tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
                tb.Width = filePath.Value.ToString().ToString().Length * 12;// 125;
                tb.Height = 25;
                tb.Text = filePath.Value.ToString();
                Canvas.SetTop(tb, y+ 25);
                Canvas.SetLeft(tb, x + 25);
 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                //External Program
                if (Path.GetExtension(filePath.Key.ToString()) == ".pdf")
                {
                    var path = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Document%20Handling%20Viewer;component/Resources/pdf.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                    p.ImagePath = path.ToString();
                    p.OriginalImagePath = filePath.Key.ToString();
                    p.ImageName = filePath.Value.ToString();


                }
                else
                {
                    p.ImagePath = filePath.Key.ToString();
                    p.OriginalImagePath = filePath.Key.ToString();
                    p.ImageName = filePath.Value.ToString();
                }
                p.Width = 100;
                p.X = x;
                p.Y = y;
                x = x + p.Width + 5;
                if (x + p.Width >= System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)
                {
                    y = y + 150;
                    x = 0;
                }

                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => _canvas.Children.Add(p)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message, "File Load Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the textblock doesn't change its style...its not bold, its not vertically placed on the bottom and it doesnt wrap. It just hugs the picture in a plain old font.
What am I doing wrong here?
[image]

**Edit** I commented out the TextBlock and the image path still shows up. Is it the ImagePath dependency property that's showing up? i'm confused

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add textblock to canvas:

```
_canvas.Children.Add(tb);
```

**Edit**

if you have textblock in Picture usercontrol, you must not create new in code behind.

in Picture.xaml you should define name of the textblock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1 />
```

in the c# code replace line: <strike>`TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();`</strike> with:

```
TextBlock tb = p.TextBlock1;
```

Comment: The tb gets added with the Picture:Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => _canvas.Children.Add(p))); I tried adding it separately and it turns out the same. The Textblock is there, just with no formatting

Comment: In the code sample in your question you are creating new textblock. You are setting properties of the new textblock, not the textblock in Picture.